# Access evaluated function arguments R

Tags: r, function, arguments, closures

How is it possible to access evaluated arguments to a function in case arguments have missing values.

Assuming the function is defined like.

```
foo <- function(...){
# function body
}
```

How to access arguments to function in its body, if some arguments are missing?

In case of no missing value, the answer is just

```
foo <- function(...){
  args <- list(...)
}
```

But this will not work if we do a call like `foo(1,,3)`.

And other way I was able to find

```
foo <- function(...){
  args <- as.list(match.call())[-1]
}
```

Gives a list of arguments but they are not evaluated. For example for call `foo(rnorm(10), 1, 2)` args will contain unevaluated arguments, that I have sometimes troubling evaluating. 
Is there any meaningful way to do this?

*UPD* I need this because I want to write a wrapper functions that record arguments to function calls and return values. For example,

```
matrix_w <- function(...){
  args <- list(...)
  res <- matrix(...)
  return(res)
}
```

In a case of most calls it will work, but for call `matrix_w(rnorm(20), , 2)`, it will not be able to process arguments in `args <- list(...)`, but `matrix(rnorm(20), , 2)` works correctly.

Comment: @Thomas
`foo <- function(...){ cat("AAAA")}`. `foo()`. `foo(1,,3)` works fine

Comment: Your example works, but why on earth would you want that? What is the advantage to describing missing values by simply not putting them in, as opposed to using NA?

Comment: @raptortech97 I want to write a wrapper for functions that will write down arguments to every call. I will update the question.

Comment: It remains unclear to me anyway what you are hoping to do. The updated function-example would just return a matrix with one column and nothing about the 'args'-list.

Comment: I still think you're going at it the wrong way.  Try to explain *why* you want to call a variety of functions via wrappers without simply passing default values for the required arguments (for example), not to mention why you want to embed that many layers of functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want them evaluated, you probably just should evaluate them yourself

```
matrix_w <- function(...){
  args <- as.list(match.call())[-1]
  eval.args <- lapply(args, function(x) tryCatch(eval(x), error=function(z) x))
  do.call(matrix, eval.args)
}

matrix_w(rnorm(10), , 2)
```

Comment: Won't that have scope problems?

Comment: If you want the evaluated values, you need to be able to evaluate them in the current context. I'm having a hard time imagination a practical scenario where this method would change the behavior of the function when it's still possible to know the values of the passed parameters.